# How to properly set up, make or include concern in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport-concern

Usually, concerns are located in

`app/controllers/concerns`.

But I want to make and separate concerns for admin side.

`app/controllers/admin/concerns`

Given I set up some sample codes,

```
# app/controllers/admin/concerns/test.rb
module Test
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :test
  end

  def test
    render json: 'test concern'
  end
end
```

# ALSO tried...,

```
module Admin
  module Test
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      before_action :test
    end

    def test
      render json: 'test concern'
    end
  end
end
```

# then include like, include Admin::Test

How to properly call or include the test concern in my admin controller.

```
class Admin::ShopsController < Admin::BaseController
   include Admin::Test # doing this,
   # got uninitialized constant Admin::Test
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related explanation has been written in official guide.

> All right, Rails has a collection of directories similar to $LOAD_PATH in which to look up post.rb. That collection is called autoload_paths and by default it contains:
>
> Any existing second level directories called app/*/concerns in the application and engines.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

The reason why `app/controllers/admin/concerns` isn't loaded is it's not a second level directory.

Since files in the second level concerns directory are automatically loaded, in this case you sould put the test.rb file in the `app/controllers/concerns/admin`.

Or adding `app/controllers/admin/concerns` to autoload path, but it's not highly recommended because this is out of rails design pattern.

Comment: Hi @Kabukimono if i'm going to push it even out of rails design patter,
In application.rb i have to add config.autoload_paths += %W(Rails.root.join('lib') Rails.root.join('app/controllers/admin/concerns')), is this correct append?

Comment: That is the case, append ``config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/controllers/admins/concerns"]" `` to ``application.rb`` In addition, you need to remove the namespace in this module. However, such customization is not preferable as it creates confusion.

Comment: @Kubukimono, this one works for me config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app/controllers/admin/concerns"
Thanks for the help :)